# Azure TopicExists and QueueExists issue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

If I have a topic and a queue with the same name within a given namespace, then calling Namespace.TopicExists() or Namespace.QueueExists() causes an error. Has anyone run into this, and short of creating a new namespace, what work around/solution did you use?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exact same issues a few days ago. It seems this is a limitation in Azure Service Bus (a ridiculous one I must say) that if you have a queue by the name `xyz` then you can't have a topic, relay or event hub by the name `xyz` in the same namespace even though each entity type serves a different purpose. One possible workaround is to create a different namespace as you suggested. Other possible workaround would be to prefix your name with entity type e.g. `queue-xyz`, `topic-xyz` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Having a queue and topic with the same name in Service Bus is not allowed.

The addressing model in Service Bus follows this pattern:

sb://{serviceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{path} where path can be a queue, topic, or relay name.